# How can I create HttpRequest (in C#) with attached files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httprequest, integration-testing

As title says, can find plenty of resources on posting *to* an endpoint (from JS, for example), but how do I construct a `HttpRequest` (in C# .Net core) with files?

### What I've Tried

```
var myRequest = new DefaultHttpContext().Request;
myRequest.Form.Files // GET only!
```

I can't seem to `set` the Files collection (`IFormFileCollection`), I can only `get` it.

### Further Context

This is to integration test an endpoint. Except I have to hit the method, not reach it via URL (for one reason or another). The method accepts a `HttpRequest` and parses out the `Form.Files` collection. Hence I need to add some files for my assertions.

Comment: Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: Right, `Files` is read only. You call the `Add` method to add files to the collection... Seems like you'd want to do something like `WebRequest.Create(url)` rather than getting the current request...

Comment: You want the contents to be a mime attachment which is added to the body and starts with a new line with two dashes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng No, not even close

Comment: @DavidG : There is nothing wrong with my suggestion.  MIME is the way you add files to an HTML message.

Comment: try converting bytes to base64 string and post

Comment: @jdweng My point it that it doesn't answer the question. And even if it did, you wouldn't care about that since you'd be creating a new [`FormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile?view=aspnetcore-5.0) object.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, as I've never used this content type. Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?
 using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "your url");

                var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("your file path");

                var content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                request.Content = content;
              var response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

Comment: @HereticMonkey - thanks for the suggestion but that's a different type (that returns a `HttpWebRequest` from the Net namespace, I want a `HttpRequest` from the core namespace)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Pretty sure that is a read-only collection so you can't use `.Add`

Comment: @DavidG : Why is OP even using a FormFile?  Look at Title of the Posting.  The OP say TRYING.  Why is he trying something that is wrong.

Comment: @DavidG I was assuming the OP was mistaken in what they were doing, because there is no reason to add files to a request while it is in flight. Hence the remainder of my comment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yup, hence my initial comment too. It's not clear what is being asked here.

Comment: This is to integration test an endpoint. Except I have to hit the method, not reach it via URL (for one reason or another). The method accepts a `HttpRequest` and parses out the `Form.Files` collection. Hence I need to add some files for my assertions. You will now tell me this approach is incorrect, I assume - but my hands are tied. I simply need to construct a `HttpRequest` and pass it to the method. Surprised it's this difficult. Appreciate all the input so far.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this clarification.

Comment: `HttpRequest` is an abstract class, you can create your own inheritor/mock for testing purposes.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see the `Append` method! I'll give this a go....

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try something like this:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
{
    var bla = new DefaultHttpContext().Request;
    bla.Form.Files.Append(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "file.txt", "file.txt"));
}
```

Comment: This could be the one, I wasn't aware of the append method since I've never needed to manually construct a request like this. Thank you very much, will try it and report back.

Comment: We may be on different versions but I don't have access to `Internal`, not a recognised namespace.

Comment: I believe the fully qualified name is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile`

Comment: I'm using the one that "ships" with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, which is 2.1.0 (pretty old already). But you could always implement IFormFile yourself, it's not that big.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by take advantage of the following Method

```
public async Task<string> UploadFile(string filePath)
{
    
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
    }

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"File [{filePath}] not found.");
    }
    using var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    using var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
    form.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    form.Add(new StringContent("789"), "userId");
    form.Add(new StringContent("some comments"), "comment");
    form.Add(new StringContent("true"), "isPrimary");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_url}/api/files", form);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FileUploadResult>(responseContent);
   
    return result.Guid;
}
```

this method was snipped from a good blog: https://codeburst.io/upload-download-files-using-httpclient-in-c-f29051dea40c

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
var formFiles = new FormFileCollection();
var formValues = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>() { };
var formCollection = new FormCollection(formValues, formFiles);
context.Features.Set<IFormFeature>(new FormFeature(formCollection));
```

Fill in the formFiles and formValues variables based on what you're trying to test. The key here is setting the feature to your custom FormFeature. That will cleanly plug into the default behavior of .Form and ReadFormAsync

PS: This is for **unit testing** assuming you're not trying to send a real file to the server side, otherwise mustafa hassan's answer works